# Creating sliding windows of NaN padded elements off 1D NumPy array

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, time-series, vectorization

I have a time series `x[0], x[1], ... x[n-1]`, stored as a 1 dimensional `numpy` array. I would like to convert it to the following matrix:

```
NaN,        ... , NaN ,   x[0]
NaN,        ... , x[0],   x[1]
.
.
NaN,  x[0], ... , x[n-3],x[n-2]
x[0], x[1], ... , x[n-2],x[n-1]
```

I would like to use this matrix to speedup time-series calculations. Is there a function in `numpy` or `scipy` to do this? (I don't want to use for loop in python to do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) -

```
def nanpad_sliding2D(a):
    L = a.size
    a_ext = np.concatenate(( np.full(a.size-1,np.nan) ,a))
    n = a_ext.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided     
    return strided(a_ext, shape=(L,L), strides=(n,n))
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: a
Out[41]: array([48, 82, 96, 34, 93, 25, 51, 26])

In [42]: nanpad_sliding2D(a)
Out[42]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  48.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  48.,  82.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  48.,  82.,  96.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  48.,  82.,  96.,  34.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  48.,  82.,  96.,  34.,  93.],
       [ nan,  nan,  48.,  82.,  96.,  34.,  93.,  25.],
       [ nan,  48.,  82.,  96.,  34.,  93.,  25.,  51.],
       [ 48.,  82.,  96.,  34.,  93.,  25.,  51.,  26.]])
```

**Memory efficiency with `strides`**

As mentioned in the comments by @Eric, this strides based approach would be a memory efficient one as the output would be simply a view into the `NaNs-padded` `1D` version. Let's test this out -

```
In [158]: a   # Sample 1D input
Out[158]: array([37, 95, 87, 10, 35])

In [159]: L = a.size  # Run the posted approach
     ...: a_ext = np.concatenate(( np.full(a.size-1,np.nan) ,a))
     ...: n = a_ext.strides[0]
     ...: strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided     
     ...: out = strided(a_ext, shape=(L,L), strides=(n,n))
     ...: 

In [160]: np.may_share_memory(a_ext,out) O/p might be a view into extended version
Out[160]: True
```

Let's confirm that the output is actually a view indeed by assigning values into `a_ext` and then checking `out`.

Initial values of `a_ext` and `out` :

```
In [161]: a_ext
Out[161]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  37.,  95.,  87.,  10.,  35.])

In [162]: out
Out[162]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  37.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  37.,  95.],
       [ nan,  nan,  37.,  95.,  87.],
       [ nan,  37.,  95.,  87.,  10.],
       [ 37.,  95.,  87.,  10.,  35.]])
```

Modify `a_ext` :

```
In [163]: a_ext[:] = 100
```

See the new `out` :

```
In [164]: out
Out[164]: 
array([[ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.],
       [ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.],
       [ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.],
       [ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.],
       [ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.]])
```

Confirms that it's a view.

Finally, let's test out the memory requirements :

```
In [131]: a_ext.nbytes
Out[131]: 72

In [132]: out.nbytes
Out[132]: 200
```

So, the output even though it shows as `200` bytes is actually just `72` bytes because of being a view into the extended array that has a size of `72` bytes.

---

One more approach with [`Scipy's toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) -

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

out = toeplitz(a, np.full(a.size,np.nan) )[:,::-1]
```

Comment: Which has the added benefit of only using up `2L-1` elements of memory, rather than `L^2`

Comment: This fails _catastrophically_ (out-of-bounds memory accesses) with `nanpad_sliding2D(np.array([48, 82, 96, 34, 93, 25, 51, 26]))`, and `nanpad_sliding2D(a[::-1])`. You should be using `a_ext.strides[0]`, not `a.strides[0]`

Comment: @Eric Good catch, it should be `a_ext.strides[0]`! Thanks, edited.

Comment: The stride version is 30,000 time faster than the scipy version, for n = 10000

Comment: But if any calculation using `a_ext` makes a copy, that will be full size.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure. So, with problems that would use some kind of reduction, would suit creating such a 2D array of sliding elems.