# Rolling concatenation array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I want to implement a rolling concatenation function for numpy array of arrays. For example, if my numpy array is the following:

```
 [[1.0]
  [1.5]
  [1.6]
  [1.8]
  ...
  ...
  [1.2]
  [1.3]
  [1.5]]
```

then, for a window size of 3, my function should return:

```
 [[1.0]
  [1.0 1.5]
  [1.0 1.5 1.6]
  [1.5 1.6 1.8]
  ...
  ...
  [1.2 1.3 1.5]]
```

The input array could have elements of different shapes as well. For example, if input is:

```
[[1.0]
 [1.5]
 [1.6 1.7]
 [1.8]
 ...
 ...
 [1.2]
 [1.3]
 [1.5]]
```

then output should be:

```
 [[1.0]
  [1.0 1.5]
  [1.0 1.5 1.6 1.7]
  [1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8]
  ...
  ...
  [1.2 1.3 1.5]]
```

Comment: The input doesn't look like an array.

Comment: edited question

Comment: If you are willing to pad with NaNs/some-other-invalid-specifier to keep a 2D shaped array, take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683601/creating-sliding-windows-of-nan-padded-elements-off-1d-numpy-array

Comment: This isn't really a numpy question, it looks more like a list concatenation.  You're starting and finishing with a ragged list, which means there's nothing in `numpy` that will make your life easier.

Comment: @DanielForsman all those individual elements are actually numpy arrays and not lists. the overall structure is an array of arrays

Comment: Don't do that.  if you have an `ndarray` with `dtype=object` you're almost certainly doing `numpy` wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your array into a list.  There's no purpose in having an array of arrays in `numpy`.

```
l = arr.tolist()           #l is a list of arrays
```

Now use list comprehension to get your elements, and concatenate them with `np.r_`

```
l2 = [np.r_[tuple(l[max(i - n, 0):i])] for i in range(1, len(l)+1)]
```